# TinyMCE making app to hang on iOS

Tags: ios, tinymce

I'm making an ajax request and then I init TinyMCE for all textareas that came with the request's response. It works just fine on all browsers, except iOS Safari (I've tried only on 6).

What it does on iOS is to work perfectly the first time, but then, when I open a document (make that request again, init TinyMCE again for textareas) it just hangs on the loading screen. I've seen that after I open the document for the first time (when it works) no ajax request returns successfully.

```
$.ajax({
        url: BASEURL + "/Expander/GetDocument",
        data: { id: id },
    }).done(function (data) {
        $wrapper.empty().append(data);
        initTinyMCE();  
});
```

Here's my init()

```
function initTinyMCE() {
tinystovalidate = [];
tinyMCE.init({

    selector: "textarea.tinymce",
    valid_elements: "@[id|class|title|style|data-options|data-*]," +
"a[name|href|target|title]," +
"#p,-ol,-ul,-li,br,img[src|height|width],-b,-i,-u," +
"-span[data-*]," +
"-span[data-mce-type],hr",
    extended_valid_elements: "-span[data-*]",
    schema: "html5",
    menubar: false,
    statusbar: false,
    toolbar: "bold | italic | strikethrough | bullist | numlist | alignleft | aligncenter | alignright | Link",
    init_instance_callback : "myCustomInitInstance",
    encoding: "xml",
    width: "100%"
});
```

}

I just upgraded to 4.0 thinking it would solve my problem, but without success. Any ideas?

Update: it seems that all async requests stop working after I initialize tinyMCE, but the others work OK.

Comment: I have solved the problem. It was caused by SignalR :)